# Apple pay with stripe invalid shipping address

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, applepay

User authorises the payment via delegate method:

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                       didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment
{
    //my code here
}
```

The payment is then used in following method to make token:

```
    [Stripe createTokenWithPayment:payment
                    completion:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error)
```

It is not making any token rather showing the user this error;

> PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusInvalidShippingContact

I want to know if this is mine error or just user is not providing sufficient information.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong delegate method to handle payment validation.
The corect one is

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                   didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment
                            completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus status))completion;
```